# How to determine that every object has been deleted from a Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to design a snake game. The snake is drawn on a canvas using rectangles joined successively and it's position is updated using an alarm callback as shown below:

```
def move(self):

    #move the snake here
    #root is the top level widget

    self.alarm_id = self.root.after(500, self.move)
```

After a player completes a stage in the game I want to remove the snake from the canvas using the canvas.delete method and draw a new snake that has advanced features.

I attempted this but the new snake is being drawn before the old snake gets cleared from the canvas, even though I am performing the operations sequentially. Is there a way that I can avoid this overlap of operations? I was thinking of a way to programmatically determine that every rectangle in the old snake has been removed from the canvas. I looked through the documentation but so far I haven't been successful.

Comment: There is no cacheing of objects -- when you delete something, it should be gone immediately. Of course, you won't _see_ the change until the event loop gets a chance to redraw the window. But then again, you won't see your new items either. The old ones will go away and the new ones added in an imperceptible amount of time. Perhaps if you show us the delete code we can spot an error. There should be nothing special you need to do to delete items before adding new items.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your canvas is called `self.canvas`, I think you can use `self.canvas.find_all()`, which returns a tuple of objects currently on the canvas. Once this returns an empty tuple, you can draw your next snake.

Comment: I just tried that. It's returning zero before every object is removed from the canvas. I think canvas.delete() just registers the object for deletion, returns and leaves the whole job to the mainloop. So it might be possible that a second call to canvas.find_all() would return zero because the objects are already set for deletion.

Comment: This is what eventually worked for me:

I created another canvas on top of the original canvas. I drew my snake on this new canvas. When time comes to create a new snake, I just destroy the canvas on the top by calling top_canvas.destroy() and creating a newer canvas on top of the base canvas. It's working perfectly.

Comment: That's a more complicated process that I would hope; but hey, if it works, it works!